# Formatting a file using bash script

Tags: bash, gnuplot

As part of my degree course I have to use software which outputs big lists of data points.  the problem I'm having is that it outputs it in such a way that i cant plot it (not without manually formatting it first).  The raw output looks like this:

```
kpt#   1, nband= 30, wtk=  1.00000, kpt=  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 (reduced coord)
  -3.34630  -3.17801  -3.09372  -3.02971  -3.02971  -2.99649  -2.99399  -2.92282
  -2.83147  -2.83147  -1.71295  -1.43814  -1.43814  -1.35290  -0.76039  -0.68874
  -0.63265  -0.62874  -0.62874  -0.41856  -0.19886  -0.19886  -0.18178  -0.08505
  -0.01900   0.03106   0.03140   0.03140   0.04786   0.07255
 kpt#   2, nband= 30, wtk=  1.00000, kpt=  0.0101  0.0101  0.0000 (reduced coord)
  -3.28432  -3.17790  -3.09155  -3.01881  -3.00521  -2.99279  -2.98718  -2.91048
  -2.83086  -2.83038  -1.71286  -1.43814  -1.43810  -1.35288  -0.75994  -0.68868
  -0.63260  -0.62875  -0.62873  -0.41848  -0.19909  -0.19886  -0.18140  -0.08502
  -0.01886   0.02667   0.03126   0.03590   0.04781   0.07262
.
.
.
 kpt#   3, nband= 30, wtk=  1.00000, kpt=  0.0202  0.0202  0.0000 (reduced coord)
  -3.25059  -3.17763  -3.08747  -3.03929  -3.00146  -2.99159  -2.96062  -2.89743
  -2.83133  -2.83014  -1.71274  -1.43817  -1.43810  -1.35287  -0.75943  -0.68865
  -0.63250  -0.62885  -0.62877  -0.41829  -0.19976  -0.19888  -0.18036  -0.08499
  -0.01851   0.02198   0.03084   0.04028   0.04753   0.07283
 kpt#   4, nband= 30, wtk=  1.00000, kpt=  0.0303  0.0303  0.0000 (reduced coord)
  -3.25108  -3.17577  -3.08771  -3.04025  -3.00164  -2.98867  -2.96080  -2.89726
  -2.83695  -2.83100  -1.71270  -1.43829  -1.43819  -1.35287  -0.75914  -0.68881
  -0.63236  -0.62892  -0.62883  -0.41799  -0.20076  -0.19897  -0.17884  -0.08492
  -0.01820   0.01707   0.03016   0.04442   0.04683   0.07314
```

Basically I need a bash script to put all the list of numbers in between each line starting 'kpt#' on one line, deleting the lines starting 'kpt#' and putting the line number at the start of each line like so:

```
 1    -3.34630  -3.17801  -3.09372  -3.02971  -3.02971  -2.99649  -2.99399  ...
 2    -3.28432  -3.17790  -3.09155  -3.01881  -3.00521  -2.99279  -2.98718  ...
 3    -3.25059  -3.17763  -3.08747  -3.03929  -3.00146  -2.99159  -2.96062  ...
```

Which would allow me to plot it straight away! Any help massively appreciated. Cheers
Jack M

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in a file called `data.txt`

```
grep -v 'kpt#' data.txt | nl -nln
```

The `grep -v` removes the header lines and the `nl -nln` adds left-justified numbers to the lines.

Comment: clever one! but the OP needs the data matching a "kpt-line" to be on one line, you solution doesn't handle the joining part...

Comment: Good point. Didn't read the question completely. This will get closer: `sed -e 's/kpt#.*/;;/' data | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/;;/\n/g' | nl -nln`

Answer (score 1):

If *awk* is acceptable:

```
awk 'END {
  print kpt, r
  }
/kpt#/ {
  if (kpt)
    print kpt, r
  r = x
  sub(/,.*/, x, $2)
  kpt = $2 
  next
  }
{
  r = r ? r FS $0 : $0
  }' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `sed`

```
sed 's/^kpt# *\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/' input | sed 'N;N;N;N;s/\n/ /g'
```